# How do I backup Device Folders and Camera Photos to different Google accounts?

Tags: backup, xiaomi, google-photos, android-11, google-backup

Currently, my camera folder is by default synced to my personal Google account. I would like to backup my Whatsapp Media folder to another account. However, Google photos settings don't let it so. They can be backed up to the same account.

A method I found after searching is creating another User profile. I am using Redmi Note 10 Pro and have options to create a Second Space, but the crux is that the second space starts from fresh.No wifi settings, No apps downloaded, Nothing is set up. Even when I try 'Move data' to move Whatsapp (for both the spaces), all it does is install a fresh Whatsapp.
Moving the Whatsapp media folder to the Second space might be an option. But it's not practical.

1. I want to continue using Whatsapp in the first space itself. So, I would have to transfer manually now and then
2. The option for 'Move Data' in my device shows only app settings to move. There is no option to move files and folders.

Moreover, I am not very sure that a Second space can really solve this problem. Would backup from Second Space go on when I using First space? I won't be able to spend a lot of time on Second space, making the backup option yet ineffective.

A solution to this problem would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this [Shelter App](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/net.typeblog.shelter/). This app uses the work profile settings of your phone to basically create two separate users files and apps in the same space. Work profile will have separate app drawer and icon for identification. Give it a try. It's perfect for your use case.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't want a cloned app on a different user profile. I can already do that. The problem with cloning is that the app generated, is with 0 app data. Its a fresh new Whatsapp. So, I can't back up my previous data even if it's linked to a different profile.

Comment: No actually my solution was to move both WhatsApp and Photos app on the other user profile. Then you can use photos app to backup whatsapp medias to the second google account (from the second user profile). And continue backing up camera media to the first google account (from the first user profile)

Comment: I have MIUI on my phone (Redmi Note 10 pro). I don't know exactly why but my phone doesn't support the shelter app. I had downloaded it from F-droid and it kept saying 'creating user profiles' for the whole time. The link for shelter app in your answer also mentions that this may not work for MIUI

Comment: Oh my bad I didn't realize you're on MIUI before posting the answer. Actually the MIUI utilizes the work profile feature to create clone applications (inbuilt feature of MIUI) and unfortunately work profile can be used by one at a time. So this solution is potentially useless for you. I am not deleting the answer since this can help someone else out there.